# SELECT non duplicated rows with priority value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

I have a table that contains rows with measurements. For the same batch id, more than one measure can be specified. I want to get the correct values under the following conditions:

- If there is only one row for a given batch, the measure is valid
- If there is more than one row of the same type, the measure is NOT valid and the type returned should be 'Invalid', with value = 0
- If there is more than one row of different type (one 'Acquired' and one 'Verified'), the row returned must be the 'Verified' one

Sample data:

```
create table measures (
  batch  int,
  type   varchar(24),
  value int
);

insert into measures select 01,'Verified',10;
insert into measures select 02,'Acquired',34;
insert into measures select 03,'Verified',22;
insert into measures select 03,'Verified',24;
insert into measures select 04,'Verified',32;
insert into measures select 04,'Acquired',34;
insert into measures select 05,'Acquired',42;
insert into measures select 05,'Acquired',44;
```

Sample output:

```
01   Verified   10
02   Acquired   34
03   Invalid    0
04   Verified   32
05   Invalid    0
```

Comment: Your first condition seems to contract the other two.

Comment: That's a really strange way to write an INSERT statement. What's wrong with the VALUES clause?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: The db engine is SQL SERVER, I have added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using windows functions:

```
;WITH CountTypesPerBatch AS
(
    SELECT batch, type, value,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'Verified' THEN 1 END) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY batch) AS verified,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'Acquired' THEN 1 END) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY batch) AS acquired,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY batch 
                              ORDER BY IIF(type='Verified',1, 2)) seq
    FROM measures
)
SELECT DISTINCT batch, 
       CASE 
          WHEN verified > 1 OR acquired > 1 THEN 'invalid' 
          WHEN verified = 1 THEN 'verified'
          ELSE 'acquired'
       END,
       CASE 
          WHEN verified > 1 OR acquired > 1 THEN 0
          ELSE value
       END
FROM CountTypesPerBatch
WHERE seq = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f3983/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is a bit hard to follow.  You can do what you want with conditional aggregation.  It think the logic is:

```
select batch,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then max(type)
             when min(type) = max(type) then 'Invalid'
             else coalesce(max(case when type = 'Verified' then 'Verified' end), 'Invalid')
        end) as type,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then max(value)
             when min(type) = max(type) then 0
             else coalesce(max(case when type = 'Verified' then value end), 0)
        end) as value
from measures m
group by batch;
```